# PowerShell file rename and counter issue

Tags: powershell, rename, counter

I have made a very simple ps1 script that rename my txt files with an "ID" number like

```
Card.321.txt
```

This works for simple lines, but I need a mass rename of lines, so I need something different.

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.txt | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Card.{0:D3}.txt' -f $i++)}
```

But I can only properly run it if there are no other files named `Card.xxx.txt`
and every day I get one new file that I store in an archive folder after it got renamed.

how can I make a script that doesn't try to do a mass renaming task?

I need a counter that can continue from yesterdays task performed with the same script.

```
Card.321.txt
Card.322.txt
Card.323.txt
Card.324.txt
Card.325.txt
ToDaysFiledToBeRenamed.txt
```

Comment: The files that need to be renamed. How are they different? Is it simply they are not Card.XXX.txt and they could be nothing else?

Comment: The files only different is the number, Card.326.txt and tomorrow will be Card.327.txt and on friday it needs to be renamed to Card.328.txt

the file have a totaly different name then it comes in to export folder.

and the storage folder holds files from Card.001.txt to todays file named Card.326.txt

And the mass renmae scripts dont like that are files in the folder already named with Card.xxx.txt so i need a script that can count the files and just rename the newfile and not to try renaming them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this. Not the most efficient but should be easy to read

```powershell
$thePath = "C:\temp"
$allTXTFiles = Get-ChildItem $thePath *.txt
$filestoberenamed = $allTXTFiles | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -notmatch "^Card\.\d{3}$"}
$highestNumber = $allTXTFiles | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -match "^Card\.\d{3}$"} | 
        ForEach-Object{[int]($_.BaseName -split "\.")[-1]} | 
        Measure-Object -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

$filestoberenamed | ForEach-Object{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Card.{0:D3}.txt' -f $highestNumber++)}
```

Collects all the files and splits them into two groups. Using `$allTXTFiles` we filter all the files that have the "Card" naming convention and parse out the number. Of those number determine the current highest one as `$highestNumber`.

Then we take the remaining files as `$filestoberenamed` and put them through your `Rename-Item` snippet using `$highestNumber` as index.

**Known Caveats**

This would not act correctly if there is ever a file with the number higher than 999. It would allow the creation of one but it currently I am only looking for files with 3 digits. We could change that to `^Card\.\d+$` instead. Depends on what logic you would want.

Comment: @wdac If this answered your question please consider marking this as answered using the green check mark next to this post. Welcome to SO